# Text cut without scroll bars, but no position:fixed in my css

Tags: css, text, scroll, overflow, scrollbars

In desperate need for help as I've already spent 2 hours fixing this to no avail.

The text on this site http://www.asianhospitalfederation.com/about is cut without scrollbars. I checked my stylesheets and all my overflows are visible, and I have no position styles.

I really don't know what to do anymore. Thanks in advance to those who will help!

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to accomplish here?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I pasted the wrong url. It's supposed to be http://asianhospitalfederation.com/about . I've been trying to get all the text to show up, which can only be done when the scroll bar works till the real page end.

Comment: I'm editing with Chrome, but I've been cross checking with Firefox and mobile.

Comment: What do you mean by trying to make all the text to show up? The text is already showing up once you scroll down. Above that there is a .content with a table in it.

Comment: Really? The "The Conference" part plus two paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum? Hmm, curious. I've asked several people to check and it does not show up. The first paragraph gets cut after the fourth line. I wonder if this is an issue beyond the codes. Thank you though!

Comment: Well the url: http://www.asianhospitalfederation.com/about is showing a header with two columns of text beneath it. However the url: http://www.asianhospitalfederation.com/   is not!

Comment: And I am also using Chrome :)

Comment: The home page really does not have text underneath as it's just a landing page. I'm curious re the /about though. It's supposed to be just one column of text with the title "The Conference". Are the titles of those two columns "Lorem Ipsum"?

Comment: here is how it looks like to me: http://www.asianhospitalfederation.com/images/screenshot.png see how the scroll bar ends but the text is obviously cut?

Comment: Yes!
The first column is `<p class="rtejustify"` </p> with a span inside and </br>.
The second column is <p> with a span inside it.
Why are you working with spans here if I may ask?

Comment: Could be a caching problem.
Could be your `overflow` code you got in some places-- although i doubt this.

And a quick browser check shows me it's showing up correct ;)

Comment: Try to give it a height! That might show it correct for you.

Comment: I'm using a cpanel that automatically puts in spans even when I keep on erasing it. I did try putting in a height earlier - from min-height to 2000px to auto to 100%. nothing worked :(

Comment: You need to share your css and htlm here. I'll put it in a fiddle and help you out. 
But again, your lore ipsum is showing correct (even after a cross browser check).

Comment: Apologies for the late response! It was five in the morning when we were talking. Here's my CSS for that part: http://www.asianhospitalfederation.com/sites/all/themes/jackson/styles/styles.css

Comment: Still can't seem to find what's wrong. :/

Comment: Hey there, 
Noticed you aligned your text on the left. 
At this stage I can see a horizontal and vertical scrollbar on the "About" page. I wouldn't put a horizontal scrollbar in there if I were you. I think it might have something to do with the width in your css ;)

I did check out your css. it is the same as in the "inspect element" and cross browser checked and all seems working and the text is not cut like in your example! 
I do understand what you are saying, but since I can not see it on my "inspect element", I am not able to help you at this stage.

Comment: Hi! I've been tweaking it a bit today 'cause I really cannot figure out this whole mysterious missing scrollbar. I decided to try the modules and cpanel layout on Drupal 7, but now I cannot seem to fix the alignment of my content! I want the entire text part to be aligned with the map banner, ending just before the menu boxes. I'm a bit wary of putting position:absolute as I want this to be compatible with various browsers of different resolutions. But really, this is so confusing.

Comment: It's my first time to use drupal. I had used WP in the past, but to be honest, it's been literally years since I last made an entire website, so please excuse the abundance of questions and thank you for your patience :)

Comment: No worries. There are no stupid questions, but only stupid answers :)

I've never worked with Drupal so I'm afraid I can't be of much help. 
If I may do a suggestion..... repost the whole thing and add Drupal as one of the tags. 
I'm sure that will help more.

Comment: Already made a separate thread. :) but thanks a lot for your help!